# Connect to DB2 with Windows credentials

Tags: sql-server, vba, db2, ado

I am working on a VBA project, in which I need to connect to both and SQL- and a DB2-Database. I am using ADODB connection in both cases. The SQL works fine, and is using the Windows credentials. I can get the DB2 connection to work by passing the username and password, but not using Windows credentials (they are the same). Please see the connection string for examples:

*This SQL connection string works fine:*

```
objConnection.connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=False;Data Source= " & strServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & strDatabase
```

*This DB2 connection string works as well, as long as I pass the password in the open method:*

```
strConnection = "Provider=IBMDADB2.1; User ID=" + nlUsername + "; Data Source=DB_" + strDatabase + "; Persist Security Info=False"
objConnection.Open(strConnection, nlUsername, nlPassword)
```

*I wanted the SQL method on DB2 - So I tried this, which does **NOT** work:*

```
objConnection.connectionString = "Provider=IBMDADB2.1; Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=False; Data Source=DB_" & strDatabase
```

Is it even possible to connect to DB2, without passing a username and password? I do I have to prompt the user for these in order to connect?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming we are talking about DB2 for LUW.

A simple way of doing this is to enable client-side authentication. Set the following instance configuration parameters on the DB2 server:

```
update dbm cfg using authentication client trust_clntauth client trust_allclnts yes
```

You will need to restart the instance for the changes to take effect (`db2stop`/`db2start`).

On the client catalog the database in question with client-side authentication:

```
uncatalog db yourdb
catalog db yourdb at node whatever authentication client
```

These last two steps (`uncatalog`/`catalog`) may not be necessary if the database is currently cataloged without explicit server-side authentication option.

Note that such configuration is not very secure, because it allows any Windows user to connect to the database (any database on the DB2 server, actually) without authentication once they log in to Windows. You may want to tighten up security on the database by revoking all grants from the PUBLIC pseudo-group and grant specific permissions to the application login ID only.

Alternatively, you can enable Kerberos authentication, but it is a much more involved process, as [described in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0011990.html?lang=en).

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I should have mentioned that I do not actually have administrator rights to the database (its a work thing), so I am not capable of making those changes. It seems like I have to prompt the user for password when they connect to the DB2 database.